# Unable To Connect to SQL Server Express Database from One PC To Another

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have 2 PC's on my at-home network and when I use this Microsoft connect utility trick to test database connection, I can connect to the database in SQL Server Express on the PC that SQL Server Express is installed on with no problem.

But when I using the same utility trick on the other PC and try to test the same database connection, I get an error

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen server does not exist or access denied

I have Norton Security Suite on the PC where SQL Server Express is installed on, and added a rule to open port 1433 and even disabled "Smart Firewall" and get the same error. I even added a DB user (Used in .UDL utility shown below) with all rights, same error. Any ideas on a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default SQL Express doesn't have TCP/IP enabled, and by default listens on a dynamic port when it is enabled.  You can use SQL Server Configuration Manager to both enable TCP/IP and disable dynamic ports and configure SQL Server to listen on port 1433.

[image]

And once you do you can connect with just the hostname.  No port number or `\SQLEXPRESS` required.

Comment: Fantastic David... That worked. Now I have another problem. I added the database connection to my Visual Studio Express 2017 C# project and can use a DataGrid to see the data in one of the tables. But if I select "Show Table Data" or "Open Table Definition" in Visual Studio I get an error dialog box "An Incompatible SQL Server Version was Detected". The database is on the other PC with SQL Server Express 2019 installed. Any help on this?

Comment: No.  You can try to update Visual Studio, or get SQL Server Management Studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I've got SQL Server Management Studio on the PC that SQL Server Express is on, not on the PC where I run Visual Studio Express 2017. Probably have up update Visual Studio but not sure what version is compatible with SQL Server Express 2019

Comment: Do you know if I can "Downgrade" SQL Server 2019 to SSE 2017 so it will work completely with Visual Studio Express 2017 ?

Comment: There is no downgrade of instances or databases.  Why not just go to the current Visual Studio, or use some other tool to manage the SQL Database?

Comment: I found this article that says a database can be downgraded.. https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb435.aspx

Comment: That's an export.  Yes you can dump the DDL and the data and load them again.

Comment: You have to change your firewall to let traffic in and out on port 1433.  It's not open by Win10's firewall by default nor by SQL installer. This will drive a lot of people crazy.